# How to execute a http request when device is about to close in android

Tags: android, http

When a user want to exit my app an asynk task is executed before my app is closed.My problem is that when my app runs in background and the user decide to close his device this asynk is not executed.How can i solve this problem?

Comment: have you considered using background Service? as a solution

Answer (score 0):

You don't, its a bad design.  No matter what happens, you can't prevent a device from running out of battery power, being dropped and having the battery fall out, or having your app killed due to low memory conditions.  You can't rely on being informed of when the app is closed.